# Searching for compression library in c# that supports rar format

Tags: c#, compression, rar

I want to add in my application functionality to decompress (and optionally compress) files in various format. I have libraries that supports zip, gzip, 7zip and bzip2. But still not found library that support rar.
I know that rar is commercial, but maybe there is some .net library that could be used to decompress rar-s? The best would be free library, but library with small price is also acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compression algorithm is closed source but the decompression algorithm is open source. The author encourages people to broaden support for RAR decompressors, and a number of portable versions exist.
for decompress rar file you can use [C# (.net) interface for 7-Zip archive dlls](http://dev.nomad-net.info/articles/sevenzipinterface)

Answer (score 5):

Try [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/). It supports extraction of RAR files and everything else that [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) supports.

Answer (score 0):

My project [SharpCompress](http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/) extracts RAR and other formats in native C# with no external DLLs needed.